# Onblur function askaquestionTEST.php:100 Uncaught ReferenceError: validLastName is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onblur

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, onblur

So this is weird, i have two inputs a lN and fN, obviously first name and last name inputs. But for some reason the oblur event on my last name is not working, I am trying to have different output for first or last name. Im thinking i might just rewrite a function to do both but i hope you cant find the error. Also, they are really similar so idk whats going on.

```
<div class = "fiftypercentofwidth">
                    <!-------------
                        <h5>Your Name:</h5>
                        <span class = "righter"><input type="text" name="clientName"></span>
                        <br><br>
                        ------ >
                        <!-- Client email address ------------------------------------------------------------ -->
                        <!------
                        <h5>Email Address:</h5>
                        <span class = "righter"><input type="text" name="emailAddress"></span> 
                        ---->
                        <!--- First Name ------------->
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col">
                            <label for="fN">First Name</label>
                                <input type="text" onblur="validateName(fN)" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" id="fN" required maxlength="50">
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--Last Name -------------->
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col">
                            <label for="lN">Last Name</label>
                                <input type="text" onblur="validLastName(lN)" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" id="lN">
                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Email -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col">
                            <label for="eMail">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" onblur="validateEmail(eMail)" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="eMail" required maxlength="254">
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
```

-----------the javascript is here----------------------------

```
function validateName(x){
    var re = /[A-Za-z]$/;

    if (x.value == ""){
        x.style.background = '#e35152';
        x.style.color = 'white';
        x.value = "Please enter your first name";   
            } else {
                if (!re.test(x.value)){
                    x.style.background = '#e35152';
                    x.style.color = 'white';
                    x.value = "Please Use Only Letters";
                        } else {
                            x.style.background = 'white';
                            x.style.color = 'black';
                            }
                }
}


function validLastName(x){
    var re = /[A-Za-z]$/;

    if (x.value == ""){
        x.style.background = '#e35152';
        x.style.color = 'white';
        x.value = "Please enter your last name";
            } else {
                if (!re.test(x.value)){
                    x.style.background = '#e35152';
                    x.style.color = 'white';
                    x.value = "Please Use Only Letters";
                        } else {
                            x.style.background = 'white';
                            x.style.color = 'black';
                            }
                }
}
```

So i fixed this code myself, but if anyone can tell me any pointers on this i would appreciate it.

FIXED CODE BELOW:

```
function validateName(x){
    var re = /[A-Za-z]$/;
    var lastName = document.getElementById('fN');
    var firstName = document.getElementById('lN');

    if (x.value == ""){
        x.style.background = '#e35152';
        x.style.color = 'white';
        fN.value = "Please enter your first name";  
        lN.value = "Please enter your last name";
        return false;
            } else {
                if (!re.test(x.value)){
                    x.style.background = '#e35152';
                    x.style.color = 'white';
                    x.value = "Please Use Only Letters";
                    return false;
                        } else {
                            x.style.background = 'white';
                            x.style.color = 'black';
                            return true;
                            }
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't assign handlers with inline `eval` - attach listeners with Javascript instead, to separate presentation from content, to make sure the function in question has scope, and to make the code more readable. Try something like:

```
function validateName(x) {
  // ...
}
document.querySelector('#fN').addEventListener('blur', e => validateName(e.target));
```

Comment: I tried it and nothing happened plus i dont see how that will help. After all the first name i have working but the last name is not..